# How to create MIDI file using hexadecimal information in C++

Tags: c++, hex, midi

I'm trying to create a MIDI file from scratch in C++.
I'm using this website as a resource: https://intuitive-theory.com/midi-from-scratch/ .

Since MIDI requires it to be encoded in Hex, i've written a program that creates a MIDI file and pastes HEX code in it like this:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std; 

int main(){
    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open ("output.mid",ios::binary);
    char buffer[44] = {static_cast<char>(0x4D,0x54,0x68,0x64,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x06,0x00,0x01,0x00,0x01,0x00,0x80,0x4D,0x54,0x72,0x6B,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x16,0x80,0x00,0x90,0x3C,0x60,0x81,0x00,0x3E,0x60,0x81,0x00,0x40,0x60,0x81,0x00,0xB0,0x7B,0x00,0x00,0xFF,0x2F,0x00)};
    myfile.write(buffer,44);
    myfile.close();

}
```

However this won't even open on any MIDI player because the "file is corrupt". I don't understand why this is happening.

Thanks

Comment: `static_cast<char>(0x4D,0x54,...)` isn't casting all of the items in that list to `char`s [it is casting the last one and discarding the rest](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator).

Comment: Why are you using `static_cast` at all here?

Comment: @tadman Some of the numbers are too big to fit in a `signed char` most likely.

Comment: @user4581301 Then time for `unsigned char` or `uint8_t` to be sure.

Comment: im using static cast because when I don't use it I get the error: error: narrowing conversion of '128' from 'int' to 'char' inside

Comment: Suggestion: Make an array of `unsigned char` and cast it to `char*` in the call to `write`. Eg: `unsigned char buffer[44] = {0x4D,0x54,0x68,0x64,0x00,...};` and then `myfile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(buffer),sizeof(buffer));`. Note: In general be really, really careful with `reinterpret_cast`. It tells the compiler to turn off its brains and trust you. If you're wrong, the program will [be goofy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) and you get NO warning.

Comment: Another note: I replaced the 44 in the call to `write` with `sizeof(buffer)` so you can change the `buffer` size in one spot and not have a screw-up writing too much or too little.

Comment: Why the <expletive deleted> didn't I write an answer?

Comment: Thanks, user4581301. This makes a whole lotta sense!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char buffer[] = {static_cast<char>(0x4D,0x54,0x68,0x64,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x06,0x00,0x01,0x00,0x01,0x00,0x80,0x4D,0x54,0x72,0x6B,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x16,0x80,0x00,0x90,0x3C,0x60,0x81,0x00,0x3E,0x60,0x81,0x00,0x40,0x60,0x81,0x00,0xB0,0x7B,0x00,0x00,0xFF,0x2F,0x00)};
```

does not cast all of the comma separated values to `char`. Instead, because `staic_cast` can only handle one value at a time, it invokes the [comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator) which will leave you with the last value discard the rest.

Instead you are a lot better off making `buffer` the right "shape" and then casting it to `char` when passing it to `write`.

```cpp
int main(){
    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open ("output.mid",ios::binary);
    unsigned char buffer[] = {0x4D,0x54,0x68,0x64,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x06,0x00,0x01,0x00,0x01,0x00,0x80,0x4D,0x54,0x72,0x6B,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x16,0x80,0x00,0x90,0x3C,0x60,0x81,0x00,0x3E,0x60,0x81,0x00,0x40,0x60,0x81,0x00,0xB0,0x7B,0x00,0x00,0xFF,0x2F,0x00};
    // unsigned char can fit any of the given values
    // Removed the 44. The compiler can figure the number of elements out from the 
    // number of initializers. Usually this is safer. Now you can add or remove 
    // a few bytes without also having to change the element count

    myfile.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(buffer), //casting here
                 sizeof(buffer)); // Letting compiler figure out how many bytes to write
    myfile.close();

}
```

Note: Be really, really careful with `reinterpret_cast`. It tells the compiler to turn off its brains and trust you. If you're wrong, the program will [break](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) and you get NO warning from the compiler and the runtime results can be utterly inexplicable until after you've figured out what happened.